# Common legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, legend

I am plotting grid in matplotlib. I have a 3*2 subplot grid like this:

[image]

I am plotting line charts in every subplot and each color of the line specifies a category. 
Let's say color_name = { cat1 : red ,  cat2 : black , ...}
Now, meaning of color is same in every subplot but they may contain only the subset of color_name dict categories. I need a common legend for the plot which contain color - category pair from the dict color_names.
I have searched a lot but I am not getting a method to make legend directly using dict so as to contain each key-value pair from dict only once.
Here the X-axis contain dates and y-value is for every day.

Code:

```
def graph_data(data):
''' Return html for graph for one department '''

fig, axes = plt.subplots( nrows=3,
                          ncols=2,
                          sharex = True,
                          figsize=(14, 10),
                          facecolor = 'w' , 
                          )

rownames = sorted(data.keys())
beautify(fig, axes, rownames )

plt.close()

color_name = get_color_name_dict()

for i, metric in enumerate(sorted(data.keys())):
    for j, device in enumerate(sorted(data[metric].keys())):
        ax = axes[i , j]

        ylow = 10000
        yhigh = 0

        for page in data[metric][device].keys():
            dd = data[metric][device][page]

            x = dd.keys()

            y = [statify(dd[_date]) for _date in x]

            ylow = min(ylow , min(y))
            yhigh = max(yhigh, max(y))

            ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
            ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

            ax.plot(y , color = color_name[page], label = page , linewidth = '2')

            ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y')

            for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
                tick.set_rotation(45)


            fig.autofmt_xdate()

        ax.set_ylim([ylow-200 , yhigh+200])



fig.tight_layout()
# tight_layout doesn't take these labels into account. We'll need 
# to make some room. These numbers are are manually tweaked. 
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.18, top=0.95, right=0.95, bottom = 0.05)

imgdata = cStringIO.StringIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, format='png' , facecolor = fig.get_facecolor())

s = '<img alt = "embedded" src = "data:image/png;base64,%s"/>' % imgdata.getvalue().encode("base64").strip()

orig_stdout = sys.stdout
f = open("test.html" , "w")
sys.stdout = f

print s

sys.stdout = orig_stdout
f.close()

print "done"
mpld3.show(fig)
#return s
```

Beautify function:

```
def beautify(fig, axes, rows):
''' Beautify the plot '''
style.use('ggplot')

cols = ['Desktop' , 'Mobile']

for ax in axes[:,0]:
    ax.set_ylabel("Median (ms)")




pad = 5 # in points

for ax, col_name in zip(axes[0], cols):
    ax.annotate(col_name, xy=(0.5, 1), xytext=(0, pad),
                xycoords='axes fraction', textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='center', va='baseline')

for ax, row_name in zip(axes[:,0], rows):
    ax.annotate(row_name, xy=(0, 0.5), xytext=(-ax.yaxis.labelpad - pad, 0),
                xycoords=ax.yaxis.label, textcoords='offset points',
                size='large', ha='right', va='center')
```

Comment: You have to use `figlegend`: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figlegend and http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/figlegend_demo.html If you need more detail post your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped :)